# How can I visualise $f(k,x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{kn+1}}{(kn+1)!}(-1)^n$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

We can be sure, that
$$\sin(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}(-1)^n$$
And, of course, $\sin(x)$ relates with circle. Which figure or infinite curve generates
$$f(k,x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{kn+1}}{(kn+1)!}(-1)^n$$
for example, when $k=3$? How can I visualise it?